# Spring Integration: JUnit test Router

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to know if there is a way to Junit test the spring integration router without having to have the input and mapped channels defined in two different context files as shown in the spring integration sample projects?

I have multiple routers defined in my project. I can not create so many context files.

```
    <int:gateway id="accountBuilder"
    service-interface="some.package.AccountGateway" default-request-channel="accountRequest"  default-reply-channel="allAccounts"/>

<int:channel id="accountRequest"/>
<int:channel id="allAccounts"/>
<int:splitter input-channel="accountRequest" output-channel="accountRequests" ref="accountSplitter" method="split"/>

<int:channel id="accountRequests">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="accountServiceTaskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:router input-channel="accountRequests" ref="accountRouter" method="routeAccountRequests">
    <int:mapping channel="accountType1HeaderEnricher"/>
    <int:mapping channel="accountType2HeaderEnricher"/>
    <int:mapping channel="accountType3HeaderEnricher"/>
    <int:mapping channel="accountType4HeaderEnricher"/>
</int:router>

<bean id="accountMessageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore" />

<bean id="searchResultMessageStoreReaper" class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
    <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="accountMessageStore" />
    <property name="timeout" value="2000" />
</bean>


<int:channel id="accountType1HeaderEnricher"/>
<int:header-enricher input-channel="aAccountType1HeaderEnricher" output-channel="retailRequest">
    <int:header name="accountType1CorrelationId" expression="headers.correlationId" />
    <int:header name="accountType1SequenceSize" expression="headers.sequenceSize"/>
    <int:header name="accountType1SequenceNumber" expression="headers.sequenceNumber"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<int:channel id="account1Request"/>

<int:splitter input-channel="account1Request" output-channel="account1Requests" ref="account1Splitter" method="split"/>

<int:channel id="account1Requests">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="accountServiceTaskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:router input-channel="account1Requests" ref="account1Router" method="routeAccount1Requests" default-output-channel="aggregatedAccount1HeaderEnricher">
    <int:mapping channel="account1Request1"/>
    <int:mapping channel="account1Request2"/>
</int:router>
```

Comment: Actually it depends on what you are going to test. Maybe it will be just enough to instantiate `MethodInvokingRouter` and invoke its `handleMessage`. Show your case, please

Comment: Hi Artem, Thanks for the reply. I have updated the question with the code snippet. Basically, I have two level routing. The first one routes to different account types and for each account type, the second level router, routes to different requests. All are defined in the same file. I need to unit test these routers individually without  bringing in the other routers into action.

Answer (score 0):

OK. as far as all your channels are dirrect, or in other words `SubscribableChannel` and you have concrete endpoint subscribed to them, you can simply mark them with `auto-startup="false"` and provide stub handlers from JUnit test code to those channel, which are appropriate in each test-case. Or invoke `start()` on desired endpoint using their `id`